# C++ comparison with string literal results in unspecified behavior, почему в QT нет ошибки

Tags: c++, g++

Здравтвуйте. Пожалуйста, объясните где я неправ.
Уменя такой код:

```
 char* Usr; Usr = getenv("USER"); if (Usr == "madmentat") {cout << "User madmentat detected" << endl;}
```

Вообще, я начал изучение программирования на Си++ с Qt и там это прокатывало, а вот в блокнотике ручками почему-то не выходит.
При компиляции выдается следующая ошибка:

> warning: comparison with string literal results in unspecified behavior [-Waddress]

Comment: `Usr == "madmentat"` сравнивает указатели, для сравнения содержимого строк следует использовать `::std::strlen`, предварительно убедившись, что `Usr` не null.

Comment: Все же сравнивать лучше `strcmp()`, а не `strlen()`

Comment: *на Си++ с Qt и там это прокатывало* - что означает прокатывало? Уточните детальнее. С `char*` не на плюсах ни на Qt это работать не будет (я описал пару исключений, но случайно на них попасть маловероятно). Может предупреждение не выдало, но то такое. Или вы не `char*` использовали?

Comment: Да там в таких случаях используются QString и все нормально работает, я, видимо, подумал, что char по сути нечто наподобие, а оказалось не так. Вообще, я часто не понимаю что делаю и как в итоге работают мои программы, у меня подход почти шаманский. В данном примере я решил задачу, использовав std::string user; User = usr;

Comment: @Harry Переоткроем? Тут выходит QString попутали с `char*`

Comment: @nick_n_a Пока - никаких оснований: в тексте вопроса сравнение `char*`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По русски: Такое сравнение даст непредвиденный результат. А точнее не даст результата вообще, т.к указатели на сторки (адреса, `char*` хранит адрес где находится текст, а не сам текст) - гарантировано не совпадут (хоть и совпадёт содержимое). Используйте `strcmp` (или `lstrcmpA` если хотите WINAPI).

Но есть несколько случаев когда так можно делать.

Если вы заранее присвоили в `char*` константное значение, и каждое значение привели к константному, либо работаете исключительно с константами - тогда так делать можно.

Например

```
 const char* value1 = "value1";
 const char* value2 = "value2";
 char* a = (char*)value1; // Хоть и избавились от константы, менять текст нельзя
 if (a == value1) { /*совпало*/};
```

Или если сделали приведение

```
 bool checkUsr(char * user) {
    if (strcmp(user,value1 )==0) user = (char*)value1;
    if (strcmp(user,value2 )==0) user = (char*)value2;
    if (user == value1) { /*сработает*/}  
     }
```

Правильно писать вот так

```
  сhar* Usr; Usr = getenv("USER"); if (strcmp(Usr,"madmentat")
     {cout << "User madmentat detected" << endl;}
```

*Вообще, я начал изучение программирования на Си++ с Qt и там это прокатывало, а вот в блокнотике ручками почему-то не выходит. При компиляции выдается следующая ошибка*

Конечно в QT можно, только не с `char*`, а с `QString`

```
  QString Usr = getenv("USER");/* вызвали Конструктор */
  if (Usr == "madmentat" /*вызов оператора*/) { /*сработает*/}
```

Потому что вызывается не сравнение указателей на строку, а оператор сравнения. Если вы хотите вне QT использовать что-то похожее, и в ваших либах нету подходящей - создайте класс, реализуйте и пользуйтесь.  (Реализацию на QT можно подглянуть тут http://github.com/radekp/qt/blob/master/src/corelib/tools/qstring.cpp).

```
class MyStr {
    char * str;
   public:
      MyStr() { str="";}
      MyStr(const char * value) { str = (char*)value;} // конструктор
      MyStr(char *value) { str = value;}// конструктор
     bool operator == (const char *value2) { // Оператор
         return (strcmp(str,value2)==0); // Упрощенно, без проверок на null
         }
     };
// Теперь вы можете делать как в QT
 MyStr Usr = getenv("USER"); if (Usr == "madmentat")  { /*всё ок*/}
```